# How to use replace() to replace words in a list?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, replace

I am trying to make a list from my web scraping but any time there's a space in comes out as '%20'. For example, 'Good Day' would become 'Good%20Day'. I tried using replace() but it said that can't be used on lists. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
number = 1

while number < 10:

    containers = page_soup.findAll("span", {"class":"css-133coio etbu2a32"})

    container = containers[number]

    con_str = str(container)

    split_str = con_str.split('/browse/')

    split_wrd = split_str[1]

    needWord = split_wrd.split('"')

    final_Word = needWord.replace("%20", " ")

    print(final_Word[0])

    number += 1
```

code is kinda ghetto but it works.

Comment: Can you share more of your program, including an example of the HTML or at least the contents of `containers`? Do you have no other choice than to convert the data to a string and split it like that? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case-with_underscores` style. You appear to be mixing multiple naming conventions.

Comment: yeah i figured it out by finding the [0] of needWord first and then replacing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**findAll** attribute return list , so you should replace each element in the list.

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("span", {"class":"css-133coio etbu2a32"})

for index, word in enumerate(containers) :
  word = word.replace('%20'," ")
  containers[index] = word
print(containers)
```